# Join two different types of databases together

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, ms-access

I have two databases, one MSSQL and the other in Access.

Right now, inside the access file, the mssql tables are set up as linked tables so queries can be written using tables from both databases. (e.g. `"select * db1.table1 where db1.table1.somevalue not in db2.table1"`, or select into tables like that one)

These queries need to be moved into a VB.NET project, but still be linked to the access file.

I think what I am needing is a Database object that can have tables from 2 different connections, (ie the SqlClient and OleDb connections)

Is this possible? If so, how? Or do I need to rewrite the queries using loops or something?

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is query your access database to get some result set and that pass that result set as a parameter to a stored procedure in your MS SQL database.  You would just have to transform your results from access into XML to be passed as a xml variable as a parameter.  And then in your stored procedure you can convert the XML to be a table variable and you can use it just like a regular table.

Answer (score 0):

THere is no reason you can't create an MS Access .mdb with Links to your MS Access Database and your SQL Server database

Access Db #1 Contains Access Tables and Data.

SQL Db Contains your MS SQL Tables.

Access Db #2 contains links to the tables in Access DB #1 as well as links to the tables in your SQL Server Db. This .mdb files ALSO contains your query defs required by your vb.net project.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can just connect to the Access database. All the internal objects--including the links to SQL Server tables--should be accessible to your vb.net project.